# How Outlook 2007/2010 is shading message headers

Tags: email, outlook, email-headers

There is a feature in Outlook 2007/2010 called "Shade messages headers when reading mail" : it includes next/previous button in front of each replies headers of a message, allowing to go to previous/next replies in the message.
I would like to know how Outlook is doing this in order to reproduce it programmatically.

Thank you

Comment: Would you please upload an image?

Answer (score 1):

It just looks for `From:` at the beginning of a line in the email, nothing more.

You can confirm this by sending yourself an email with the headers out of order:

```
-----Original Message-----
To: E.J. Dyksen
From: E.J. Dyksen 
Sent: Monday, June 04, 2012 9:35 PM
Subject: RE: Test email
```

In this case, the line with `From:` is what Outlook highlights.